# Javascript HighCharts reading from a different format

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts and i currently have 2 arrays which I would like to stop reading from and start reading the data from my object.

Here is the code i currently have:

```
items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2'];
Quantity = [10 , 5];

        jQuery('#container').highcharts({

            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: mydata
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Items Title'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Items',
                data: Quantity
            }],
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}<br/>',
                shared: true
            },


            plotOptions: {

                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function () {

                                console.log('Clicked');


                            },
                        },
                    },
                },

            },

        });     

The above displays 2 items of height 10 and 5.

Now what I need to do is to be able to read this data instead:

var mydata = {
    "items":[{
        "id":"123",
        "name":"item name here",
        "subitems":[{
            "id":"567",
            "name":"subitem 1"
        },
            {
                "id":"657",
                "name":"subitem 2"
            }],

        "somthing here":null,
    },
        {
            "id":"456",
            "name":"item name here too",
            "subitems":[{
                "id":"567",
                "name":"subitem here"
            },
                {
                    "id":"657",
                    "name":"subitem here roo"
                }],

            "somthing here":null,
        }]
};
```

The quantity values need to be the subitems count so in the case of the data above it would be 2,2

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

https://jsfiddle.net/b3wii/0Lx77f1a

If you click on a column it reads the mydata and displays the subitems. To get the subItem count just use mydata.items[i]['subitems'].length. To update the existing Item values change currentItemY or currentItemX.

```
click: function (e) {
        if(this.series.name != 'SubItems'){
            let currentItemName = items[this.index];
          let currentItemY = this.y;
          let currentItemX = this.x;

          let newCategories = [];
          let newSeries = [];

          for(let i in mydata.items){
            if(mydata.items[i]['name'] == currentItemName){
              for(let j in mydata.items[i]['subitems']){
                newCategories.push(mydata.items[i]['subitems'][j]['name']);
                newSeries.push(mydata.items[i]['subitems'][j]['quantity']);
              }
            }
          }

          chart.update({
            xAxis: {
              categories: newCategories
            },
            series: [{
              name: 'SubItems',
              data: newSeries
            }]
          });
        }
},
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I'm looking for. You have 1 hardcoded part where you put the items and the other part are the subitems...I'm going to hard just 1 data source where I must get all from...makes sense?

Comment: @Farley2016 What part do you mean with hardcoded? You can also get the data from ajax.